# A package.json file without dependencies?

Tags: typescript, npm

Trying to figure out what `peerDependencies` stands for... I came up with this `package.json` content file. It belongs to a library project which is distributed over there.

```
{
    "name": "...",
    "version": "...",
    "description": "...",
    "author": "...",
    "license": "Unlicense",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
      "build": "typings install && tsc --outDir dist/"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "@angular/core": "^2.0.0",   <<<<<<<<
        "@angular/http": "^2.0.0",   <<<<<<<<
        "@angular/common": "^2.0.0",   <<<<<<<<
        "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0",   <<<<<<<<
        "core-js": "^2.4.0",   <<<<<<<<
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",   <<<<<<<<
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",   <<<<<<<<
        "zone.js": "^0.6.17"   <<<<<<<<
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/core": "^2.0.0",   <<<<<<<<
        "@angular/http": "^2.0.0",   <<<<<<<<
        "@angular/common": "^2.0.0",   <<<<<<<<
        "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0",   <<<<<<<<
        "core-js": "^2.4.0",   <<<<<<<<
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",   <<<<<<<<
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",   <<<<<<<<
        "zone.js": "^0.6.17",   <<<<<<<<
        "typescript": "^2.0.0",
        "typings": "^1.3.2"
      }
}
```

1. Why a same package is added on `devDependencies` and on `peerDependencies`?
2. Why `dependencies` is not used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since npm 3, `peerDependencies` are [not automatically downloaded](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/110924823920/npm-weekly-5) anymore. Instead nom will warn if a dependency is not already installed.

The reason for structuring a `package.json` this way that I would imagine is:

- **developers** of this package need to download and install  the dependencies and use the list in `devDependencies`
- **consumers** of this package do not necessarily need to download the dependencies as they may already have them installed in their project. However, if they do not already have them, the presence of `peerDependencies` will guarantee they will get a warning on install (which they will need to resolve manually).